# jquery mousetrap to toggle offcanvas

Tags: jquery, toggle, mousetrap

So I have this code to show my favorites sidebar when clicking "f" on my keyboard:

```
Mousetrap.bind('f', function () {
    const bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#favorites');
    bsOffcanvas.show();
});
```

The only problem is, when clicking "f" again, the sidebar doesn't close, it wants to open again, which means, the background just keeps getting darker because the offcanvas keeps being opened. Is there a way to make a "toggle" so when pressing "f" again it closes?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that includes the details/definition for `.Offcanvas`?   Sounds like you shouldn't be using `.show()` (try `.toggle()`) - but depends on what Offcanvas is/does.

Comment: Cannot provide an example at this moment. I tried using `.toggle()` but it is the same "issue". It is a sidebar modal, like this example: https://demo.interface.club/limitless/demo/template/html/layout_1/full/components_offcanvas.html

Comment: If it's bootstrap-5's [Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/) (which it appears to be) then see .toggle(): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/offcanvas/#methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
const bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas('#favorites');
let isOffcanvasShown = false;

bsOffcanvas._element.addEventListener('shown.bs.offcanvas', function ()     {
    isOffcanvasShown = true;
});

bsOffcanvas._element.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function ()     {
    isOffcanvasShown = false;
});

Mousetrap.bind('f', function () {
    if (isOffcanvasShown) {
        bsOffcanvas.hide();
    } else {
        bsOffcanvas.show();
    }
});
```